# Android Issue switching activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, swipe

In my app, I have a normal menu where I can select from the menu and go to a different view.  Simple...

```
private void gotoSettings() 
{
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
}
```

Now I also have a method in the main view that handles flings (swipes between views):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), CommandActivity.class);

            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) 
                return false;

            // left to right swipe
            if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) 
            {
                startActivity(intent);
                MainActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slideinleft, R.anim.slideoutright);
            }
```

Now here is the thing.  On app startup, if I am in the main activity and select settings, it works fine and goes to the Settings activity.  But if I fling over to the Command activity, then fling back to the main activity, then select Settings again, it will call the same method which does this again:

```
private void gotoSettings() 
{
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
}
```

But now it automatically shows the Command activity instead of the Settings activity.  I've even debugged and have witnessed it go through the above code and right after startActivity(settingsIntent); it does not go to Settings activity, it goes to command activity.

This is very very strange, as I am TELLING it to go to Settings, but it is not.  It must have something to do with the fling, but I dont see it....?

Comment: Not sure why it formatted the code that way, I put the `s around the code

Comment: that's for inline code, for multiple lines you have to select all them and press `{}` button.

Comment: It will probably not fix the problem, but it seems you should move `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), CommandActivity.class);` inside the if-statement as there is no reason to create an Intent-instance unless it's going to be called.

Comment: @pecka ur right prolly wont fix it but no need to create the instance, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to write like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommandActivity.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), CommandActivity.class);
```